# What does general relativity say about energy-momentum relationship in unstable space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, momentum, energy-conservation, noethers-theorem

Suppose that there is an isotropic, homogenous space which is non-stationary in time (expanding/collapsing).
Let say that some package of electromagnetic radiation flows in portion of space far from gravitating bodies for large period of time.

According to Noether theorems, energy conservation stops to be applicable in this situation. Further, general relativity shows that electromagnetic radiation can be redshifted/blueshifted without any limitations.

However, space is isotropic and uniform, and Noether theorems suggests that in such environment law of momentum conservation holds. Does this mean that energy-momentum relationship stops to work in usual form? Or this means that momentum conservation also stops being applicable?

Comment: Do you mean p=Ec for photons, for instance? Not considering the big rip that probably won't change meaningfully since it's local physics. I am not certain what the meaning of momentum conservation is for objects that can no longer interact causally, though. There was also a long standing problem of how to even define total mass and angular momentum in strong gravity which hasn't been resolved until recently (or so the science news said). It may be that these quantities only exist asymptotically, which means they literally lose meaning in an expanding universe.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, I was asking for what happens with "p = E/c" relationship. However, not for extreme states as Big Rip or strong gravity just for case of ordinary expansion or contraction.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the division sign. I am getting too old for formulas. That's just sad. I don't think that will change as long as we can define momentum, energy and the meaning of the speed of light locally. Your point about momentum conservation is non-trivial, though. Momentum conservation links systems over arbitrary distances, which means that even flat expanding spacetime causes a "rip" merely by looking at a large enough scale. I don't know what to replace it with (or whether there is a replacement at all) in that scenario.

Comment: You have to take into account the gravitational energy and momentum , which will depend on global properties. See the "Related" posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a spacetime is homogeneous and isotropic, it is automatically maximally symmetric. A maximally symmetric spacetime cannot be non-stationary in time. Our universe is often described by an FLRW metric, which is isotropic and spatially homogeneous, but it has a preferential time dependence (which cannot be removed by going to a cleverly constructed coordinate system). Energy is actually not conserved in cosmology for this reason, because time translation is not a symmetry. Also, the relation $E^2 = p^2 +m^2$ in special relativity comes from $\eta_{\mu \nu} p^\mu p^\nu = m^2$ where $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is the flat space metric. In curved space, this is not true anymore.